# Twain driver scanner integration in Windows 8.1

Tags: driver, twain

We have tried to fetch images from Twain compatible scanner to scan documents and store direct into our application. It works for us until Microsoft gives update of Windows 8.1.

Has anybody idea to get scanned images from Twain compatible scanner?

Comment: Did you test with [Twacker](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/644/) on Windows 8.1? Can you scan documents successfully with it?

Comment: No, Its not working. Give error like "TWRC_FAILURE".

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with your driver. You may contact the scanner vendor and see if they have an updated TWAIN driver.